# Who's speaking at / attending Dreamforce this year?

Tags: discussion

I have a talk on the agenda for the first time in a while so I'll be in attendance this year. Who else is going or presenting? Hoping to see some SFSE faces!

Comment: What's your talk going to be on?

Comment: @MattLacey CumulusCI for developer productivity.

Comment: Funnily enough I saw that from your co-presenter elsewhere! Hopefully I can get along to it :)

Comment: I'll be attending tho not speaking

Answer (score 7):

I'll be at Dreamforce, though more than likely rarely inside the conference itself. Our company has grown a little over the years to the point that we're going to be running our own venue a short walk from the Moscone. Will post some more details in due course in case anybody fancies swinging by!

Comment: I'll be supporting this ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I'll be there. Talk not accepted as usual, because it was about cool stuff with the Reporting API, LWCs and Experience Cloud.

Answer (score 5):

I'm presenting on "Effective Branching Strategies for Salesforce Developers" as a theater session